# Java type which accepts a class AND its interfaces (contravariance)

Tags: java, inheritance, types, polymorphism

I have a class and an interface like this:

```java
interface Employee {...}

class Developer implements Employee {...}
```

Then I have classes which implement steps in the onboarding process:

```java
interface OnboardingStep<T extends Employee> {
  void perform(T newEmployee);
}

class GeneralOnboardingStep implements OnboardingStep<Employee> {
  GeneralOnboardingStep() {}

  @Override
  void perform(Employee newEmployee) {...}
}

class DeveloperOnboardingStep implements OnboardingStep<Developer> {
  DeveloperOnboardingStep() {}

  @Override
  void perform(Developer newDeveloper) {...}
}
```

The full onboarding process consists of the general onboarding plus the specific onboarding for developers.

So what I would like to do is this:

```java
abstract class OnboardingProcess<T extends Employee> {

  // This is where I need help, see below
  private final List<OnboardingStep<T>> onboardingSteps;

  protected OnboardingProcess(List<OnboardingStep<T>> onboardingSteps) {
    this.onboardingSteps = onboardingSteps;
  }

  public void perform(T newEmployee) {
    for (var onboardingStep: onboardingSteps) {
      onboardingStep.perform(newEmployee);
  }
}

class DeveloperOnboardingProcess extends OnboardingProcess<Developer> {

  DeveloperOnboardingProcess() {
    // This does not work
    super(List.of(
      new GeneralOnboardingStep(),
      new DeveloperOnboardingStep()
    ));
  }
}
```

This does not work, because the List in `DeveloperOnboardingProcess` may only contain `OnboardingStep<Developer>` and not `OnboardingStep<Employee>`.

But it should work because `Developer` implements `Employee`. (By "should work" I mean: "I wish it worked").

How can I adapt the list type in the abstract class to also accept onboarding steps for the interface?

Comment: It looks like you need `List<? extends OnboardingStep<? extends T>>`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman It’s actually `List<? extends OnboardingStep<? super T>>`.  The `super` is needed to make sure the `perform` method of every instance in the list is capable of accepting T and won’t require a subtype of T.

Comment: @VGR Yes, `List<OnboardingStep<? super T>>` did the trick. Thank you very much! If you write an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might want is this (but see below):

```
private final List<OnboardingStep<? super T>> onboardingSteps;

protected OnboardingProcess(List<OnboardingStep<? super T>> onboardingSteps) {
    this.onboardingSteps = onboardingSteps;
}
```

`? super T` means that each list element’s `perform` method is guaranteed to accept a T instance, since it will be restricting the constructor argument to steps whose type is T or a superclass of T.  So, for DeveloperOnboardingProcess, the constructor can take list elements which are an `OnboardingStep<Developer>` or an OnboardStep whose generic type is any superclass of Developer, including Employee itself.

However, one thing you cannot do is pass a `List<DeveloperOnboardingStep>`.  `List<DeveloperOnboardingStep>` is *not* equivalent to `List<OnboardingStep<Developer>>` or `List<OnboardingStep<Employee>>`, because the latter has an `add` (and addAll, etc.) method which allows an OnboardingStep, or a DeveloperOnboardingStep, or any other future subclass of OnboardingStep, whereas a `List<DeveloperOnboardingStep>` has an `add` method which will accept only a DeveloperOnboardingStep argument.

To allow, say, a `List<DeveloperOnboardingStep>` argument, use this:

```
private final List<? extends OnboardingStep<? super T>> onboardingSteps;

protected OnboardingProcess(List<? extends OnboardingStep<? super T>> onboardingSteps) {
    this.onboardingSteps = onboardingSteps;
}
```